# Query vacia, Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario de registro de pago de recibos y al ingresarlo a la base de datos, mi programa funciona perfectamente, los datos se guardan en esta, incluyendo la imagen.
El problema que tengo es que me sale un error de sintaxis en la query, pues me mustra la query vacia. Pero haciendo un var_dump() a la query, me muestra todos los datos que recoje el formulario. 
¿Cuál puede ser el error?

esta es la query que hago

[image: aca detengo la ejecucion del programa para ver que es lo que mando a la query]

aca detengo la ejecucion del programa para ver que es lo que mando a la query

y al quitarle el die() para que siga con la ejecucion me muestra lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desconosco el porque salen esos don notificaciones de Notice si en al mover la imagen al directorio especificado, se guarda el nombre de la imagen.

Al consultar phpmyadmin, se puede observar el registro insertado

[image]

Este es el codigo:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST)){

    require_once '../includes/conexion.php';
    require_once '../includes/funciones.php';
    borrarMensajes();
    //Asignacion de variables
    $bien = isset($_POST['bien']) ? $_POST['bien'] : FALSE;
    $concepto = isset($_GET['concepto']) ? $_GET['concepto'] : FALSE;
    $categoria = isset($_POST['categoria']) ? $_POST['categoria'] : FALSE;
    $tpago = isset($_POST['bien']) ? $_POST['bien'] : FALSE;
    $valor = isset($_POST['valor']) ? $_POST['valor'] : FALSE;
    $fecha =isset($_POST['fecha']) ? $_POST['fecha'] : FALSE;
    $descripcion = isset($_POST['descripcion']) ? $_POST['descripcion'] : FALSE;
    $archivo = isset($_FILES['archivo']) ? $_FILES['archivo'] : FALSE;
    $nArchivo = $archivo['name'];


    var_dump($nArchivo);

    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario']['id'];

    $ruta = '../static/img/img-bills/'; //asignacion de la ruta de imagenes
        //comprobacion del tipo imagen

        //construir un nombre para la imagen
    $now = date('m.d.y'); //fecha actual
    $random = rand(1,99);
    $rutaImagen = $ruta .$now .'-'. $random . $nArchivo; //concateno la ruta del directorio con el nombre el archivo

    if(!is_dir($ruta)){
        mkdir($ruta, 777);     
    }
    move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], $rutaImagen);

    $query = "INSERT INTO entrada VALUES (
        null,
        $usuario, 
        $bien, 
        $concepto, 
        $categoria, 
        $tpago, $valor, 
        '$fecha', 
        '$descripcion', 
        '$rutaImagen', 
        CURDATE()
        );";


    var_dump($query);

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die (mysqli_error($conexion));

    var_dump($resultado);

    if($resultado){

        $_SESSION['message']= '<p class="text-success"> Actualizacion Completa!</p>';
        header('location: index.php');

     } else { 

        $_SESSION['message']= '<p class="text-danger"> No se pudo Actualizar</p>';
        header('location: ../index.php');
    }

}


?>
```

aca mi codigo del fomulario

```
<div class="list-group">
            <a href="#!" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start active">
                <h3 class="my-2 text-center">Pagos de <?= $_GET['nombre'] ?> </h3>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="list-group m-5">
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start ">

                <form action="controller/registro.php/?concepto=<?= $_GET['id'] ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Selecciona Bien :</label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <select class="custom-select" name="bien" required>
                                <option selected>Seleciona un bien</option>
                                <?php
                                $bienes = consultaBien($conexion);
                                if (!empty($bienes)) :
                                    while ($bien = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bienes)) :
                                ?>
                                        <option value="<?= $bien['id'] ?>"><?= $bien['nombre'] ?></option>
                                <?php
                                    endwhile;
                                endif;
                                ?>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--si la categoria no tiene el conseptos, no muestre el input select-->
                    <?php
                    $categorias = consultaCategoria($conexion, $_GET['id']);

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Selecciona Categoira para : <?= $_GET['nombre'] ?> :</label>
                            <div class="col-8">
                                <select class="custom-select" name="categoria" required>
                                    <?php

                                    $categorias = consultaCategoria($conexion, $_GET['id']);

                                    if (!empty($categorias)) :
                                        while ($categoria = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categorias)) :
                                    ?>
                                            <option value="<?= $categoria['id'] ?>"><?= $categoria['nombre'] ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                        endwhile;
                                    endif;
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label class=" col-form-label">Selecciona tipo de Pago :</label>
                        <div class=" custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="tpago" class="custom-control-input" value="2" required>
                            <label class="col-2 custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Efectivo</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="tpago" class="custom-control-input" value="1" required>
                            <label class="col-2 custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">PSE</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="customRadio3" name="tpago" class="custom-control-input" value="3" required>
                            <label class="col-2 custom-control-label" for="customRadio3">Tarjeta</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Valor :</label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="$" name="valor" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Fecha del Pago :</label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="fecha" id="example-date-input">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Descripcion :</label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <textarea name="descripcion" id="" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" required placeholder="Pago Impuesto - Administracion - Mosquera - $ 300 000, # ref: 000000 999"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Comprobante</label>
                        <div class="col-9 custom-file">
                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="archivo" accept="image/png" required>
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Sube un Comprobante</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center ">
                        <button type="submit" class="col-6 btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg">Guardar Pago</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </a>
        </div>                  <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Selecciona Categoira para : <?= $_GET['nombre'] ?> :</label>
                            <div class="col-8">
                                <select class="custom-select" name="categoria" required>
                                    <?php

                                    $categorias = consultaCategoria($conexion, $_GET['id']);

                                    if (!empty($categorias)) :
                                        while ($categoria = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categorias)) :
                                    ?>
                                            <option value="<?= $categoria['id'] ?>"><?= $categoria['nombre'] ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                        endwhile;
                                    endif;
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label class=" col-form-label">Selecciona tipo de Pago :</label>
                        <div class=" custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="tpago" class="custom-control-input" value="2" required>
                            <label class="col-2 custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Efectivo</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="tpago" class="custom-control-input" value="1" required>
                            <label class="col-2 custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">PSE</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="customRadio3" name="tpago" class="custom-control-input" value="3" required>
                            <label class="col-2 custom-control-label" for="customRadio3">Tarjeta</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Valor :</label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="$" name="valor" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Fecha del Pago :</label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="fecha" id="example-date-input">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Descripcion :</label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <textarea name="descripcion" id="" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" required placeholder="Pago Impuesto - Administracion - Mosquera - $ 300 000, # ref: 000000 999"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Comprobante</label>
                        <div class="col-9 custom-file">
                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="archivo" accept="image/png" required>
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Sube un Comprobante</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center ">
                        <button type="submit" class="col-6 btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg">Guardar Pago</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: En ambos casos estás tratando de acceder a un elemento de `$archivo`, probablemente te faltó inicializar `$archivo = $_FILES['nombre_de_campo'];`. Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código del formulario.

Comment: hé mirado esa posibilidad, que depronto no me este llegando los datos de la imagen, pero no es el caso. me imprime los dato que le agino. Ya  actualice la pregunta y hé añadido el codigo del formulario

Comment: Ok, ahora, antes de comenzar a asignar variables, haz un `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES);`, nuevamente edita tu pregunta para agregar el resultado.

Comment: 1° linea var_dump($_POST, $_FILES);
die();
`array(6) {
  ["bien"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["categoria"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["tpago"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["valor"]=>
  string(3) "999"
  ["fecha"]=>
  string(10) "2020-05-09"
  ["descripcion"]=>
  string(9) "fdjnhdgfh"
}
array(1) {
  ["archivo"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "screenshot_1.png"
    ["type"]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(25) "/opt/lampp/temp/php9bThVL"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(38124)
  }
}` Llegan la informacion  sin problema